# Border-radius circle loses shape when scaling at different browser zoom levels

Tags: css, anime.js, border-radius

I have a small circle at 4px and I want to scale its size using anime.js. It works great at 100% zoom (default), but I also want it to behave the same at default zooms from 50-100%.

Example fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6x4ry3no/1/

As seen in the example fiddle, if you `'CMD' + '-'` or equivalent on Windows to zoom out, you will notice the circle becomes a rounded quadrilateral at other zoom levels between 50-100%, which is undesirable.

It seems to be loosely related to the divisibility of the zoom percentage by the width/height as at some percentages it seems to be fine.

Ideally I'd just use an SVG to avoid this but, as far as I'm aware, scaling SVGs also requires a transform to keep the shape in the same place which I'd like to avoid.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the tricks I tried worked to preserve the roundness of the circle when zoomed out—super weird.  However, if I replace the div in your fiddle with the an SVG (and remove the border-radius and bg-color from CSS), things do seem to work correctly:

```css
#circle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 4px;
  height: 4px;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" id="circle">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="red" />
</svg>
```

Comment: What's also weird is that scaling an SVG with this library no longer scales the x and y coordinates of the shape and thus keeps the circle in the same place - making this question redundant.. I must've been trying to scale it in a different way as I haven't updated the library locally. Thanks for the help!